# ASP.NET MVC 5: No aparece la opción Area en visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc

En Visual Studio 2019 no aparece la opción Area en la opción Add del menú contextual del proyecto ASP.Net MVC.

¿Alguien sabe dónde está?

Gracias

Comment: Este no es una pregunta de programación.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado:

Hay que crear manualmente la carpeta Areas y con el ratón sobre la carpeta abrir el menú contextual y seleccionar Add > Area

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta más correcta está en este enlace

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341935/visual-studio-2017-add-areas-missing

Un saludo para todos